# Tile Overlay Add Image Google Map Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I'm developing a Flutter project, but at some point I got stuck. I'm building my project on the map and I couldn't find a function to add photos to the map (google map) with a built-in Ground Overlay function like in Android Studio. Does Flutter have a ready package? All I found is that we can define tileOverlay inside the google map widget in Flutter.

I couldn't come to a conclusion because the comments on the blog sites are old.

Please help me :)